# Tomcat not launching OS X

Tags: tomcat

I used this web page to install Tomcat: http://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat7

When I enter the following code into my terminal I get these outputs:

```
Trevor-Truogs-MacBook-Pro:~ trevortruog$ /Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

The website says that Tomcat should start after I run the starting script, however nothing happens and I don't get any error messages. My question is why isn't the software actually launching?

Comment: What happens after you run `bin/startup.sh`? (Other than the output you showed above)

Comment: Nothing happens which is the confusing part. The computer just loads for a bit then keeps going as if nothing happened

Comment: have you tried to access http://localhost:8080 ? tomcat starts as a detached process...

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", do you even get a command-prompt back after running `startup.sh`? On *NIX systems, the `startup.sh` script should return quickly while Tomcat starts in the background. Try running `ps` or the Activity Monitor to see if any Java processes are running. If you have a JDK installed, use jstack to get a thread dump to see what the Java process is doing.

Comment: What happens when you access localhost:8080 in your web-browser ?